# How to use AND operator logic in Or Operator i cant solve it in interview?

Tags: c#, .net, boolean-logic

suppose i have a code like this,

```
(var1==true && var2==true)
{
    somemethod();
}
```

suppose we have a language in which we do not have && operator it is not exsis in the language then what changing in the condition to make it like (var1==true || var2==true)
and work like and operator that when both condion true then it enter in the loop and do not use any code like using if condition for both condition to make it work 
  hopes for your suggestions thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "do not use any code like using if condition for both condition"?

Comment: I'm guessing me means no nested if.

Comment: wondering if you are supposed language does support the `!` operator or not

Answer (score 7):

```
if (!(!var1 || !var2))
{
    somemethod();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

By DeMorgan's law:

a and b === !!(a and b) === !(!a or !b)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgans_laws

Comment: I was scraping my brain trying to remember what that Law was. Thanks for giving me flashbacks of high school math *shudder*

Comment: @rikitikitik hardware classes have made me way more familiar with it than I ever wanted to be x.x

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the below:

```
(!(!var1 || !var2))
```

Steps below:

```
(var1==true && var2==true)
(var1 && var2)
!(!(var1 && var2))
!(!var1 || !var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they are booleans, you could also use '&'

```
if (var1 & var2) {

}
```

which 'could' be simpler for humans to understand, then multiple negations.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (var1)
    if (var2)
        someMethod(); // var1 and var2 are both true
```